# Substituting large values of $n$ into Stirling’s formula, given the outcomes of other $n$ values

Tags: approximation, factorial

> $$n!  \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \; \left(\frac{n}{\mathrm e}\right)^{n},$$
> in the sense that the percentage error $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
>
> Show that the formula has an error of approximately $2.73\%$ for $3!$ and $0.83\%$ for $10!$.
> Find the percentage error for $60!$.

I am assuming that there is an algebraic approach, that utilizes $3!$ and $10!$ to find the solution for $60!$, rather than substituting numbers.

To turn this function into one that outputs percentage error, I converted it to: $1 - \frac{\textrm{Stirlings formula}}{n!}$.

However, my calculator still is unable to compute it. I used an online calculator and managed to solve it correctly. The topic is on factorials, so I believe there is another way of solving it that utilized $3!$ and $10!$, but can’t find it. Is there another way? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a simple relation. You can work this out by computing the logarithm of the factorial.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates).

Comment: Interesting to note that:
$$\frac{60!}{\left(10!\right)^{7}\left(10\right)^{36}}\approx1.00423...$$
$$\frac{60!}{\left(3!\right)^{28}\left(3\right)^{126}}\approx1.03433...$$
Though, I'm not aware of a generalization of such approximations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with some numbers and I´ve got good approximations. Let

$$\mathcal E(n)=\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n} \; \left(\frac{n}{\mathrm e}\right)^{n}-n!}{n!}$$

Then the approximation for relative errors of multiple n´s are

$$\mathcal E(n\cdot m)\approx\frac{\mathcal E(n)}{m}$$

For $n=10$ and several values of $m$ the results are

[image]

**Remark**

I´ve added a column with the relative differences (in percent). It shows that the numbers of that column are all far below $1\%$ (absolute value). I would call it a sufficiently accurate approximation for the most cases. A reply would be nice.

Comment: I'd say the error should probably be measured relative to $n!$ and not relative to the approximant.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, thanks. I will try to change it. Although it is useless, since the OP is not really interested in an answer-I think.

Comment: Sorry, different time zone, and I asked the question really late at night. Thanks a lot for the help. The data helped me to understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Subbota You´re welcome.